# Bower, Mondernizr and Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, bower, modernizr

I am trying to set up an new website environment in a Visual Studio 2015 project. Ive got everything working; NPM, Bower, Gulp. It is generating and minifying all my js and css, except Modernizr, which I seem to be stuck on.

I added modernizr to my bower.json file and VS created the bower_components folder. However there is no modernizr.js in the directory. I found another post on here suggesting doing a "bower cache clean" but that didn't seem to improve the situation at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: To answer your question more information is required. Can you paste the content of your `bower.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Modernizr 3.0 there is no longer an already built file in the bower package. You have to build it yourself by running `npm install` inside `bower_components\modernizr`

Source: [github issue](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1759)

Answer (score 5):

@ahmad-alfy is correct, in that there is no modernizr.js file that is included.

however you do *not* need to run npm install. You can `npm` / `bower install` any of the Modernizr URLs.

e.g. `npm install --save https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses-emoji-ambientlight`

Comment: I use `npm install` then `grunt build`. On github issues also I found this precious URL `https://modernizr.com/download?do_not_use_in_production`

Comment: that url is a web redirect, it won't work for bower or npm installs